How can I tell whether a set of short Bernoulli trials all had the same p?
I am trying to determine whether a set of vectors from two groups A and B are manifestations of the same or two different processes. Each vector is a sequence of 3 or more binary values, so I might have something like
A: [1, 1, 0]
A: [0, 1, 1, 1]
A: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
B: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
B: [0, 1, 1]
B: [1, 0, 0]
...

For biological reasons, I am expecting either a lot of 0s or a lot of 1s per vector, with some "error rate", so the probability of the sequence could be modeled as a Bernouilli trial with either a high or a low probability $p$ of observing a 1. We can assume that the "events" per vector are independent - there's probably some correlation there in some cases but for it should hopefully be negligible. The number of events per vector is bounded, usually something between 3 and 15, but the distribution of vector length can be quite variable, ie sometimes most vectors are short, in other cases most vectors are on the longer end of the spectrum.
What I am trying to calculate is the likelihood that vectors in group A and group B were generated by the same process, ie had the same $p$, or it's more likely that one had high and the other had low $p$. I do expect groups to have only one dominant process.
It seems to me that there must be a relatively straightforward way to express this, especially if I provide a prior for $p_1$ and $p_2$, but I am unsure how to get to a solution. Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated!
As a "stretch goal", I also wonder how to calcualte the confidence in the classification. Intuitively, the more of these vectors I have looked at, and depending on their respective length, I would be increasingly confident that A and B were different (or not). But I'm not sure if there's a simple way to express this confidence as a function?

Are you saying that all vectors in Group A must have the same probability parameter $p_1$ & all in Group B the same probability parameter, $p_2$? And are the Bernoulli trials in each vector independent? And does the length of the vector - the no. trials - depend on $p$ in any way?

It sounds like you are describing a mixed-effects logistic regression where $p$ is random within group (A or B) and there is a fixed group effect you wish to estimate or test.  If so, search our site for lmer logistic for solutions.

@Scortchi For the sake of simplicity, yes, I expect there to be one p for each group at most. The independence of the trials is more complicated to answer. I think we can say that they are, because most of the time when a 1 is observed in an otherwise "0" vector (and vice versa), it will be "random error". The real biology this represents is more complicated, but I think these simplifications are acceptable approximations.

@DaGaMs you can test with a goodness of fit test whether the different multiple observations within a same group reasonably follow a binomial distribution with a fixed probability. If it doesn't, then a further analysis for the difference between the two groups requires a decent biological reason and description for the discrepancy from a binomial distribution.

If you would assume that the two groups follow simple a binomial distribution, then the question doesn't seem that difficult. A simple test for the difference of binomial proportions will do, and potentially you can add in a prior. I guess that you are looking for something more complicated, but what is that? It is not clear.

(Could you please edit your question to include these clarifications?) If the no. of trials in each vector are also fixed by design, or carry no information about $p$s, there doesn't appear to be any complication & you're concerned with inference within a product-binomial model, as @SextusEmpiricus suggests.

@SextusEmpiricus I'm not looking for anything complicated, I simply didn't know where to look for a solution to the problem. My crude first approach was to simply compare the distribution of frequency of events per vector per group using a ranksum test, but that seems inelegant somehow. I was trying to find out if there's a more appropriate and maybe also more sensitive approach.

@DaGaMs but do the different vectors from the same process have the same parameter $p$ or can there be slight variations, the distribution can be betabinomial or otherwise overdispersed instead of binomial? For the binomial case, the situation can be simplified as you can just regard the total fraction or sum of the values, which is a sufficient statistic.

W.r.t. to your edit, my question's not how the no. events per vector vary if not fixed by design, but whether the no. events per vector tells you anything about the probability you're interested in. (In an extreme case each trial might continue until a certain no. of 1s is obtained.)

Suppose two dice, red & blue, have a possible bias towards coming up odd or even, & you want to investigate whether they have the same bias. Your collaborators each get a minute to toss one of the dice a few & record 'odd' or 'even'. If you assume that who's tossing the dice makes no difference, & that no-one's speeding up or slowing down their rate of tossing according to the outcomes, then all that matters is the total no. times that each die came up odd & even, & you're concerned with inference in the product-binomial model.

@Scortchi I see, apologies for the misunderstanding. The length of the vectors is truly random. They represent random slices of independent molecules from different cells, the values inside them have no influence on the slicing.
